# Changing open mode in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to make a VBA code that changes the Acces opening mode *from exclusive* mode *to shared* mode? I have a code that detects if the Acces was opened in exclusive mode and gives you an error message if it was. Is it possible to make a VBA code that automatically changes the opening mode from exclusive to shared? This is the code I'm using to determine if the user opened the database in exclusive mode or not. I want to put the opening mode change part in the `case 70` part, this is the return if the data base was opened in exclusive mode.

```
 Public Function IsCurDBExclusive() As Integer
  'Célja: Eldönti, hogy az adatbázis kizárólagos módban van-e megnyitva.
  'Visszatérés: 0, ha az adatbázis nem kizárólagos módban van megnyitva.
  '            -1, ha az adatbázis nem kizárólagos módban van megnyitva.
  '             Err ha valamilyen probléma lpett fel.

  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim hFile As Integer
  hFile = FreeFile

  'Dim lngRed As Long, lngOrange As Long
  'lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
  'lngOrange = RGB(197, 90, 17)

  Set db = CurrentDb
  If Dir$(db.Name) <> "" Then
    On Error Resume Next
      Open db.Name For Binary Access Read Write Shared As hFile
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Select Case Err
          Case 0   'Az az eset amikor megosztott módban van megynitva az adatbázis.
            IsCurDBExclusive = False
  '         MsgBox "Nem kizárólagos!"
          Case 70  'Az az eset amikor kizárólagos módban van megynitva az adatbázis.
            IsCurDBExclusive = True
            MsgBox "Kizárólagos módban nyitotta meg az adatbázist! Használja megosztott módban vagy kérjen segítséget az átállításához!", 0, "Figyelem"  'Ha kizárólagos módban van megnyitva ezt fogja kiírni.
             If ActiveWorkbook.ExclusiveAccess Then
                ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing
             End If
            'Form!MENU.BackColor = lngRed
          Case Else
            IsCurDBExclusive = Err
        End Select
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Close hFile
    On Error GoTo 0
  Else
    MsgBox "Couldn't find " & db.Name & "."
  End If
```

Comment: An Access database is opened by default in shared mode. If opened in exclusive mode, either it can't open in shared mode, or the command used to open it specified exclusive mode.

Comment: @Gustav I can't really understand what you trying to say.
My porblem is I want to close the exclusive mode and open it in shard mode using a vba code.

Comment: Your problem is, that it has been opened in exclusive mode for some reason. Prevent that. If not, when you have closed Access and reopen it, it will again be in exclusive mode.

Comment: @Gustav I understand to prevent it, but how? It's a shared file between a lot of user. Not every user knows hot set it shared if they has it opened in exclusive. I want to make it automatic if they open the database in exclusive mode, it automatically switches it to Shared mode.

Comment: Sorry, apart from user training, I don't know of any method to force opening of Access files in shared mode.